# use the system monospace font in gtk textview

Tags: python, gtk

I would like to have a GtkTextView in my (Python) program which shows text with the system monospace font. I found many ways which use an expicit font family name and size. However, I would like to use the system specified monospace font (e.g. from the ubuntu font preferences panel).

My program should be able to run on Windows as well as Linux without modifications, chosing automatically the right font.

to clarify, this is *not* what I want:

```
fontdesc = pango.FontDescription("Courier 18")
textview.modify_font(fontdesc)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use "monospace 18" as your font and it will use the system monospaced font.

Comment: what would I use, if I want the system default font size, too?

Comment: you're right, it's working. That's something I could have thought of myself. Thanks!

Comment: actually, (tested in Ubuntu 12.04) it is not working. Setting the font to "monospace" keeps the last set font size.

Comment: I'm not sure this is entirely correct.  "Monospace" is the fontconfig alias for the default monospace font.  GTK+ has its own settings in dconf where you can change the default monospace font through gnome-tweak-tool, without affecting fontconfig aliases in any way.

Comment: Hm, now I see that GTK+ itself hardcodes "Monospace", so maybe I'm worrying unnecessarily: https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/ee8eb91523fcca2c7d0c783a3289e9f72bb74770/gtk/theme/Adwaita/_common.scss#L3334-L3336

Answer (score 1):

[available since 3.16]

```
set_monospace()
```

GTK3+ Doc
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html#gtk-text-view-set-monospace

```
gtk_text_view_set_monospace ()
```

> void

```
gtk_text_view_set_monospace (GtkTextView *text_view, gboolean monospace);
```

> Sets the “monospace” property, which indicates that the text view should use monospace fonts.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **text_view** a GtkTextView
>
> **monospace** TRUE to request monospace styling