# PyGTK object that displays text

Tags: python, textview, pygtk, statusbar, glade

I am searching for a GTK Object that displays a text (only one line), but I need the text to be bigger than in a Statusbar (and maybe that I can change the font and italic/bold etc).

Normally, I created a GTKStatusbar that displays a text when I click on a button.
(I created the program with Glade):

```
self.statusbar = self.builder.get_object("statusbar")
self.searchbutton = self.builder.get_object("searchbutton")

def on_searchbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.statusbar.push(1, "Hello world!")
```

But with this method I can't display the text with a bigger letter size.

Can you please help me with my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/articles/change-the-font-of-GtkTextView.php   or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737021/use-the-system-monospace-font-in-gtk-textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Gtk.Label` has a property called `"use-markup"` which lets you use [Pango Text Markup](http://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html) in the label. For example:

```
label = Gtk.Label()
label.set_use_markup(True)
label.set_markup("<big>This is bigger text</big>")
```

You could either use the `GtkLabel` as the statusbar (for a very, very simple statusbar) or you could extend `GtkStatusbar` and pack your label into it there.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was searching for !